# How to move and rotate imported objects in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent

I'm doing a small project where I needed to create interactive 3D scene on web. I used three.js to import blender designed objects. First I tried exporting objects as JSON but it won't import into the web. Then I tried exporting the objects as separate .obj files and imported them one by one.

Now I need to make this for the user to move and rotate each objects along in Y axis only. Because my design is of House plan and I need only to rotate and move each rooms.
It will be big help if you could find me a source for this.

This is the code after I created the scene and imported objects one by one:

```
  var obj1 = {
  scene: null,
  camera: null,
  renderer: null,
  container: null,
  controls: null,
  clock: null,
  stats: null,

  init: function() { // Initialization

    // create main scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcce0ff, 0.0003);

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    // prepare camera
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 1, FAR = 2000;
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 100, 300);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    // prepare renderer
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias:true });
    this.renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(this.scene.fog.color);
    this.renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    this.renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

    // prepare container
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(this.container);
    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    // events
    THREEx.WindowResize(this.renderer, this.camera);


    // prepare controls (OrbitControls)
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.controls.maxDistance = 2000;

    // prepare clock
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // prepare stats
    this.stats = new Stats();
    this.stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.stats.domElement.style.left = '50px';
    this.stats.domElement.style.bottom = '50px';
    this.stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
    this.container.appendChild( this.stats.domElement );

    // add spot light
    var spLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.75, 2000, Math.PI / 3);
    spLight.castShadow = true;
    spLight.position.set(-100, 300, -50);
    this.scene.add(spLight);

    // add simple ground
    var ground = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200, 10, 10), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0x999999}) );
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    ground.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    this.scene.add(ground);

    // load a model
    this.loadModel();
  },



  loadModel: function() {

    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Kitchen.obj', 'models/Kitchen.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });



    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Bath.obj', 'models/Bath.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });


    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Bedroom.obj', 'models/Bedroom.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });


    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Closet.obj', 'models/Closet.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });


    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Corridor.obj', 'models/Corridor.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });

     // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Potio.obj', 'models/Potio.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });

     // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/Living.obj', 'models/Living.mtl', function(object) {

     // object.position.x = -200;
     // object.position.y = 0;
     // object.position.z = 100;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });

  } 
};

// Animate the scene
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  update();
}

// Update controls and stats
function update() {
  obj1.controls.update(obj1.clock.getDelta());
  obj1.stats.update();
}

// Render the scene
function render() {
  if (obj1.renderer) {
    obj1.renderer.render(obj1.scene, obj1.camera);
  }
}

// Initialize lesson on page load
function initializeObj() {
  obj1.init();
  animate();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener('load', initializeObj, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)enter code here
  window.attachEvent('onload', initializeObj);
else window.onload = initializeObj;
```

Comment: I cannot see any rotation / move / drag code above. Do you mean that the user should be able to move and rotate with the mouse, or that you want to move and rotate your meshes in the script ? And what did you try ?

Comment: yes, User should be able to select each object and move and rotate it (selected object) with mouse or/and keyboard.

Comment: For that you need a raycaster. Look at the threejs examples about raycasters first.

Answer (score 9):

you can save the loaded object in a variable, which you then use later to rotate it:

-add a variable: `var myObj;`

-when loading the object, set the variable

```
oLoader.load('models/Living.obj', 'models/Living.mtl', function(object) {
      myObj = object;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      obj1.scene.add(object);
    });
```

-inside the animate() function, rotate your object over time:

```
myObj.rotation.y = Date.now()*.002;
```

or do some other stuff

---

Alternatively, as your Scene structure is consistent, you can just use

`obj1.scene.children[4].rotation.y = Date.now()*.002;`

but note you will need to adjust the number everytime you Change your loading order or add lights etc, so i do not recommend it to you

To rotate it with the mouse:

```
//you need to store this to know how far the mouse has moved
var lastMPos = {};

//this function is called when the mouse is moved
function mousemove(event){

    //you can only calculate the distance if therer already was a mouse event
    if (typeof(lastMPos.x) != 'undefined') {

        //calculate how far the mouse has moved
        var deltaX = lastMPos.x - event.clientX,
            deltaY = lastMPos.y - event.clientY;

        //rotate your object accordingly
        obj1.scene.children[4].rotation.y += deltaX  *.005;  
    }

    //save current mouse Position for next time
    lastMPos = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to enable mouse events and not animations.
I need to make the user to move and rotate each objects (rooms in this scenario) . 
Anyway Thanks for the answer. Really appreciate it

Comment: i added an example how to roate it based on mouse movement

Comment: if you want to select an object, take a look at this example [link](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) you can see the Code if you click in the bottom right

Comment: Thanks alot . This helped me